# How can i use google OAuth2 in my Jersey REST Web Service

Tags: java, javascript, oauth-2.0, client-server, google-oauth

I am developing Web Service using REST Jersey. For user access and authentication i have to maintain session throughout application (like Servlet).I have planned to use google OAuth 2.0.

How to apply in my application ? ?
Any other OAuth 2.0 libraries available. please suggest?
Any Ideas where to start? If so any tutorials kindly share?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can let the servlet container handle the session for you using standard JSESSION cookies. That will save you from revalidating the access token on each REST request. Then you simply use oauth for authentication.

A lot depends on what the REST client will be, and hence what the UX will be. That will shape your architecture. The server bit is easy.